# Arduino only supports 140 LEDs

Tags: arduino-uno

I've a problem with an Arduino Uno board. It only supports 140 LEDs using the FastLED library. Any LED which is higher than that number can't be turned on or off using FastLED.

Is this related to the board, the library or any other  circumstances? And help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you read this https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/issues/288

Comment: Maybe your code or inadequate power supply? We need more info.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how fast you need to go, the apa102-arduino library by Pololu doesn't seem to have a hard limit on their LED capacity.  They say the refresh rate goes down after 60 LEDs, but don't say anything about the maximum amount of LEDs you can have.

https://github.com/pololu/apa102-arduino

The max I'm doing at a time is only a string of 48, so I haven't checked how many it can update at once.  I am, however, running a total of 180 LEDs with this library, over 5 separate "channels".

To make it even a tiny bit harder, I'm doing it with a Nano.

This library has a "slow" and "fast" way to update the LEDs.  So far, the "slow" way is faster than the BlueTooth connection I'm sending data over to update the LEDs.

They state that the "fast" method is something like 20x faster than the "slow" way, but takes a little more in-depth programming.  Since the "slow" way works for me, so far, I haven't bothered trying the "fast" way.

Other option:

Talking with a friend at my local maker space, he said that it could be due to the speed of your board vs the timing of your LEDs. If your board isn't running fast enough, it can prevent the LEDs from being updated correctly after a certain amount of LEDs.

He was also saying that if you don't have enough available memory, it can affect how many LEDs you can update.

Seeing as you have an Arduino Uno, you shouldn't have a problem with speed or memory. Without knowing what else you are running on your Arduino (code, sensors, GPS, other shields, etc.), it's hard to say what could be holding you back.

My friend's son uses the FastLED library, so I'm going off other-than-first hand knowledge here.